# Android "Widget" in Notification Bar (native or cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, widget

We try to create an app and would like to show some information for app on notification bar. I don't know how this is called on android, but some other apps have some widgets in the bar like this

[image]

I don't know how this is done and how this is called. We can not close the notification and it is still present there.
At the end we try to do this with a cordova app, but if we know how this is done native by android we can google for it and check if there is always a cordova plugin or if we have to implement this by our own.